# Pandas: LEFT OUTER JOIN where (ON) 2 Conditions that Match

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have 2 Dataframes that I'd like to combine in Pandas where two 2 conditions are met, but I'm not successfully getting there. Thanks in advance for assistance!

```
df1
    A    B    C
0   1    2    3
1   4    5    6
2   7    8    9

df2
    A    B    F
0   1    2    cat
1   4    5    dog
2   7    8    moose
```

#### Desired Result

```
df3
    A    B    C    F
0   1    2    3    cat
1   4    5    6    dog
2   7    8    9    moose
```

Attempts to `merge` that are failing that are failing:

- `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A' & 'B', how='left')`
- `pd.merge(df1, df2, on('A' & 'B'), how='left')`
- `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A' & on='B',how='left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try add to [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) multiple join keys `on=['A','B']`:

```
print pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','B'], how='left')

   A  B  C      F
0  1  2  3    cat
1  4  5  6    dog
2  7  8  9  moose
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, @jezrael!

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks! Great to be here! :-)